# How to get the shape of the Tensor obtained by tf.boolean_mask() in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to define a loss function, which calculates the loss according to different conditions. The code is as bellows:

```
def calLoss2(logits, labels, augs, noaugs):
  augs = tf.cast(augs, tf.bool)
  noaugs = tf.cast(noaugs, tf.bool)
  noAugLogits = tf.boolean_mask(logits, noaugs)
  noAugLabels = tf.boolean_mask(labels, noaugs)
  augLogits = tf.boolean_mask(logits, augs)
  augLabels = tf.boolean_mask(labels, augs)
  noaugLoss = 0.0
  if augLabels.get_shape()[0] < BATCH_SIZE:
    noaugLoss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        noAugLogits, noAugLabels)) * PENALTY_COEFFICIENT
  augLoss = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(augLogits, augLabels))
  return noaugLoss + augLoss
```

As you can see, I want to calculate the loss according to the first dimension of the variable 'augs', which I think I can get its shape using **augLabels.get_shape()[0] < BATCH_SIZE**. But the get_shape()[0] gives a '?' instead of a number of its first dimension. However, when I use get_shape() to get the shape of a tensor which is not obtained by tf.boolean_mask(), it usually gives the correct shape.

So could anybody give me some advice, how to get the shape of a tensor which is obtained by the function tf.boolean_mask()?

Comment: You can get shape of any `tensor` by doing `sess.run(tf.shape(tensor))`

Comment: Yes, I know that method. But as you can see, if I use sess.run(), I have to created numerous sessions. I don't think that is a good way. Then, in the end, I found I can get the shape of a tensor using tf.shape(tensor)[0] without sess.run() you mentioned. I don't know the reason and could you please explain it? Thank you for your suggestions.